# How to change display order of Popup window?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have 30sec timer running in my Application , after 30sec a window popups and ask for "Reset" . In some page I also have a custom popup windows to display some message.

The 30sec timer works perfect when there is no popups on the Application , but if there is a popup window called "XYZ" is on the page at same time the application times out - in this scenario my timer window shows under the "XYZ" popup window.

I also tried : `PopUpManager.bringToFront(timeOutWindow);` it doesn't help.

My question is if there is more than one popup window on the page , how to change the display order?

Your help is really appreciated , Thanks in Advance. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating the popups with addPopup() if you put them all in PopUpManagerChildList.POPUP
then bringToFront should work.

PopUpManagerChildList.POPUP is the 4th parameter of addPopup.